# Should tag 'eschatalogy' be removed or merged / made a tag synonym of 'eschatology'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that the main site has tags [eschatology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eschatology) and [eschatalogy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eschatalogy). The second is a misspelled version of first, of course. Should the misspelled version be made a tag synonym of the properly spelled version, or should it be removed altogether?

Answer (score 2):

I say the misspelled tag should be deleted. Any questions using it should be tagged with the correctly spelled tag.

We don't want another aluminum/aluminium on our hands.

Answer (score 1):

Done and done. I've retagged and synonomized this.

Comment: Oh. Why not just delete the misspelled tag?

Comment: @fredsbend I could have, but I figured if it was going to be a thing to screw up the spelling we might as well accommodate them. New attempts to abuse the english language will be corrected automatically.

Comment: For miss-spellings wouldn't it be better to rely on not having only the right thing show up in the auto-correct list?

Comment: @Caleb yeah, you're right. I forgot that it shows in the autocomplete as a synonym. Tag (and synonym removed)